# Does the .duplicated() method in Pandas has a fuzzy match in the values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fuzzy-logic

I was doing an exercise for my Data Science course that involves a dataset that contains several pieces of information regarding Google Playstore apps.

[Dataset in question](https://shorten.one/q6N54)

The exercise asked to remove any duplicate rows and columns and fill in any missing data. Checking the columns, they were okay, no duplicates. So I moved to check the only columns where duplicates might be a problem which is the 'App' column of the dataset. After all, the other data can and most likely will be repeated, since it's information that all share, hence my reasoning to filter out duplicates in the 'App' column.

Here is the problem: I used the duplicate method. It returns a series with boolean values. By adding this series I could get how many rows were duplicate - and by using the .loc method, I could extract their actual values. I used the following code:

`df_pst.loc[df_pst.duplicated(), :]`

By pure chance (and curiosity, I guess), I decided to check the values manually by index to see what apps were being repeated in the dataset. By my surprise, none of the values matched - they were simply different. I'm pasting two screenshots to illustrate what I mean.

So, after all this ordeal, my question is: do Pandas' methods use a fuzzy match for its parameters? I am fairly green to programming but I've dealt with data science some times before, and that's the only explanation I could find. There are no mentions of this whatsoever in the method's documentation. So I'm turning to the community to help me solve this burning question.

Thank you.

[Picture 1: the (supposedly) duplicates that the method returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq2dw.png)

[Picture 2: the actual entries. You can see how they are different but for some words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXHUn.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a simple example dataframe to demonstrate the issue that you're having.

Comment: No there's no fuzzy matching involved

Answer (score 0):

One theory about what is happening here is that the duplicated entries are just far apart, so you're not seeing them close to each other.

To answer you specific question: no, `df.duplicated` will only return True for rows that are exactly equal - no fuzzy matching involved.

Answer (score 0):

Note that [`df.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html#pandas.DataFrame.duplicated) only flags duplicates beyond the first.

> keep{‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default ‘first’
>
> ```
> Determines which duplicates (if any) to mark.
>     first : Mark duplicates as True except for the first occurrence.
>     last : Mark duplicates as True except for the last occurrence.
>     False : Mark all duplicates as True.
> ```

As an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
                   'b':[4,5,6,7,4,5,8,9]})

print(df.loc[df.duplicated()])
```

yields only the *'excess'* duplicated rows

```
   a  b
4  1  4
5  2  5
```

whereas

```
print(df.loc[df.duplicated(keep=False)])
```

yields the full set of rows that are duplicated

```
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
4  1  4
5  2  5
```